# How to extract variable names and variable data from the same lines to make a data frame?

Tags: r, regex, text, dataframe

I have a series of text files that look like this:

```
USABILITY DATA
Level Name: LVL_Introduction
    Time Spent: 323.233307
    Times Teleported: 6
    NumDeaths: 0

Level Name: LVL_1-1
    Time Spent: 36.760727
    Times Teleported: 1
    NumDeaths: 0

Level Name: LVL_1-2
    Time Spent: 45.953598
    Times Teleported: 1
    NumDeaths: 0

Level Name: LVL_1-3
    Time Spent: 176.440704
    Times Teleported: 0
    NumDeaths: 0

Level Name: LVL_1-4
    Time Spent: 281.797485
    Times Teleported: 0
    NumDeaths: 0
```

Each text file represents one player's data from a play session in a puzzle game from level to level. Some players reach different levels than others.

I'd like to scrape this kind of text file into a data frame that would give me a table with the Level Name (ex: "LVL_1-3") as a column header and "Time Spent", "Times Teleported", and "NumDeaths" as the Row Headers.

```
                    LVL_Introduction    Lvl_1-1    etc...
Time Spent:         323.233307          36.760727
Times Teleported:   6                   1 
NumDeath:           0                   0
```

Ideally, the script would be robust enough to work no matter which user (or level name) is involved. I've seen several different solutions for related problems, some using regular expressions, and some simply splitting strings. I'm not sure the best process to use a single line to make both a header and a data value, in a script that works across multiple files.

Thanks,
Mitchell

Comment: Are the "Level Name" values consistent across all the text files? Also, are you sure this is the way you want to structure the output dataframe? It seems like it would be more appropriate to have columns something like `c("Player","Level","Time.Spent","Times.Teleported","NumDeath")`

Comment: There is a master set of possible values, but the values can be different from text file to text file, as can the number of level entries. The levels can be (LVL_1-1 to LVL_1-5) all the way up to (LVL_4-1 to LVL_4-5) because there are 4 sets of 5 levels. There is an introduction level and a main menu. Different players reach different points in the game, so each file is a different.

Comment: @rosscova I was thinking I could melt this data frame so that I could have each user as a different column, but that would require row names like this:
Time_Intro
Teleports_Intro
Deaths_Intro
Time_1-1
Teleports_1-1
Deaths_1-1
Time_1-2
Teleports_1-2
Deaths_1-2
Time_1-3
Teleports_1-3
Deaths_1-3
Time_1-4
Teleports_1-4
Deaths_1-4
Time_1-5
Teleports_1-5
Deaths_1-5
Time_Menu
Teleports_Menu
Deaths_Menu
Time_2-1
Teleports_2-1
Deaths_2-1

Comment: Hopefully that makes sense -- there are 17 possible game levels, 3 variables I'm measuring, and many different users. I can do variables x levels or "variable by level" x user. It could be more simple to do the data entry by hand into a clean .csv, I just wanted to see if an R solution exists.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion, although it doesn't quite match what you've asked for, I think you'll find it gives you your data in a very tidy (read: useful) way:

```
library( readr ) 
library( plyr )

import <- function( datafile.name ) {

    new <- read_delim( datafile.name,
                       col_names = c( "category", "data" ), 
                       delim = ":",
                       trim_ws = TRUE )
    new <- new[ !is.na( new$data ), ]

    output <- data.frame(
        new[ new$category == "Level Name", "data" ],
        new[ new$category == "Time Spent", "data" ],
        new[ new$category == "Times Teleported", "data" ],
        new[ new$category == "NumDeaths", "data" ],
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
    names( output ) <- c( "level.name", "time.spent", "times.teleported", "num.deaths" )

    # get the username from the file name
    output$user <- datafile.name
    return( output )
}

# get a list of files
setwd( [where your files are located] )
filelist <- list.files()

# and apply the function above to all those files to create one big dataframe
df <- ldply( .data = filelist,
             .fun = import )
```

Note, I'd assume your filenames don't directly represent the user names, so you'll need to do a conversion. Something as simple as `gsub(".txt","",datafile.name)` might suffice.

If there are a lot of files to import, you may also want to multi-thread that process. Here it is across 4 cores:

```
library( doMC )
registerDoMC( cores = 4 )
df <- ldply( .data = filelist,
             .fun = import,
             .parallel = TRUE )
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I will try them out :)

Answer (score 0):

`readr` has a nice chunked read function which may be of help given you have chunked, formatted data.

Here I create a function to process the chunks - it uses `read.delim` to read the `variable: value` data and then transposes it using `tidyr::spread`

```r
library(tidyr)
library(readr)

f <- function(x, pos) {
  dat <- read.delim(text = x, sep = ":", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  return(spread(dat, V1, V2))
}
```

reading the chunks in with `DataFrameCallback` gives a `data.frame` of results via `rbind`

```
rawData <- read_lines_chunked(file = "gamedata.txt",
                              skip = 1,
                              chunk_size = 5, 
                              callback = DataFrameCallback$new(f))
```

then it's just a matter of re-formatting this to what you asked for (use of `4` for column id is not robust, but this is a clean example)

```
gameData <- setNames(data.frame(t(rawData[, -4])), rawData[, 4])[c(2,3,1), ]
gameData
#>                       LVL_Introduction    LVL_1-1    LVL_1-2     LVL_1-3
#>     Time Spent              323.233307  36.760727  45.953598  176.440704
#>     Times Teleported                 6          1          1           0
#>     NumDeaths                        0          0          0           0
#>                          LVL_1-4
#>     Time Spent        281.797485
#>     Times Teleported           0
#>     NumDeaths                  0
```